# GET different values with the same parameter name

Tags: php, cookies, get

I have ran into the problem, where i need help. I have the code like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['profile']) && '' != $_GET['profile']) {
    setcookie('asd', $_GET['profile'], time() + 2592000, '/');
}
```

I am getting the profile value and setting it to users cookie. It works fine, if there are 1 profile, bet if the url is like: http://www.example.com?profile=1&profile=2 then it overwrites the value.
What i want is to change the way so the information written to the cookie would be not overwritten, but would be written this way: 1-2, so the cookie would be like: asd  1-2

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You would need to set uri to `?profile=1-2` or `?profile1=1&profile2=2`. When you use `?var=x&var=z&var=foo` then two values will always be lost. It's the very same thing as:

```
$array = [];
$array['foo'] = 1;
$array['foo'] = 2;
$array['foo'] = 3;
```

And at this point you lost values `1` and `2`. You have **only** `3` under `$array['foo']`.

**EDIT:**
Optionally you can make URI like `?profile1=x&profile2=z ... &profile999=foo` and later in PHP:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $val) {
    // omits null values
    if (!isset ($val)) continue; 

    // omits $_GET variables not starting with 'profile'
    if (strpos($key,'profile') !== 0) continue; 

    $prof[] = $val;
}
$profiles = implode('-',$prof);
setcookie('asd', $profiles, time() + 2592000, '/');
```

Or `?profile[]=1&2&3` and in code:

```
if (isset ($_GET['profile'])) {
    foreach ($_GET['profile'] as $val) {
        $prof[] = $val;
    }
    $profiles = implode('-',$prof);
    setcookie('asd', $profiles, time() + 2592000, '/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GET parameters do not work like that.

Submitting multi-value form fields, i.e. submitting arrays through GET var, can be done as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?cars[]=Saab&cars[]=Audi
```

Now $_GET will be an array containing all values.